# Extract audio from mp4 container without re-encoding or command prompt?

Tags: audio, sound, video, export

## How can you extract the audio file from an mp4 without re-encoding?

[Mp4 videos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPEG-4_Part_14) are just [containers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_container_format) that have video and audio.

In theory the audio file should be able to be extracted quickly in its original format with no quality loss.

Edit: Operating systems at my disposal are all versions of Windows and any popular versions of Linux.

**How do you do this without using command prompt?**

Answer (score 0):

"Quickly" or "without using command prompt"?  Batchable procedures tend to be the fastest for such purposes and they more often than not use the command prompt.

For example, by using the `-codec:a copy -vn` output options of `ffmpeg` will not reencode audio and not write any video.

The problem with "without using command prompt" then means a GUI specific program which are rarely cross-platform, and you don't bother specifying the platform you use.

While this amount of attention to detail often points to Windows users, Windows 10 has become so much of a complication for serious use, a lot of people stay with older Windows versions (which need specifying) or switch systems anyway.

Comment: I made an edit to my question. I should have mentioned what OS I had access to.

Comment: I'm aware command prompt is going to be the most common way to do a batch process. I'd still like to use a GUI.